# how to get all the user folders Box API v2

Tags: java, authentication, box-api

In the v2 of the box api can't find a resource to get all the folders of an user, if i try to get the resource /folders show a 405 method_not_allowed error, but  with the /folders/0 show the level of the root,  in the v1 there is something called [get_account_tree](http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923929/ApiFunction_get_account_tree),  but in the v2 how can i retrieve all the folders of the user?

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a fully equivalent method for `get_account_tree` in v2. You'll need to make recursive `GET /folders/{folder id}` calls in order to retrieve all of the folders in a user's account.

Comment: There will be occasions when API users have to traverse the entire directory tree, so is one REST call per folder practical?  I'm not saying it isn't, just asking to be persuaded that it is.  Platform Boxer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141560/box-api-v2-0-search-feature) has said that search might be added before v2 leaves beta.  How about a call which can describe the tree as well?