# BOX API v2.0 search feature

Tags: box-api

Does the API v2 support the search feature?
Couldn't find it in the documentation.
When will it be supported?

Answer (score 0):

The V2 API does not yet support search.  It is on our roadmap to have before we take the V2 API out of Beta and make it GA.   At this point we don't have specific timing on when the Search API will be released, but it should be sometime in the next month or two.